# jQuery: clone a div and insert it after last div with sequential id

Tags: jquery, forms, clone, insertafter

I need to insert a clone of a `div` containing a `form` after the last `div` with that same class. But how can I empty all the form fields? I have the following code:

```
<span id="add">Add</span>
<div id="0" class="addr">
    <input type="text" name="a">
    <input type="text" name="b">
    <input type="text" name="c">
</div>
<script>
    jQuery(document).ready(function($){
        $('#add').on('click',function() {
            var id = $(".addr:last").attr('id');
            $(".addr:last").clone().attr('id', ++id).insertAfter(".addr:last");
        });
    });
</script>
```

Comment: .find() .each() .attr()

Comment: Try `$('#form')[0].reset();`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of cloning div, you can use html of that div to append it like this

```
$('#add').on('click', function () {
        var id = $(".addr:last").attr('id');
        var appendDiv = jQuery($(".addr:last")[0].outerHTML);
            appendDiv.attr('id', ++id).insertAfter(".addr:last");
    });
```

Comment: thanks! not sure i understand what the code is actually doing, but it works! :)

Comment: In jQuery() function, we pass div outerHTML as string to make it jQuery object.

Answer (score 1):

```
var temp = $(".addr:last").clone()
temp = $(temp).(':input').val('');
$(temp).attr('id', ++id).insertAfter(".addr:last");
```

Answer (score 1):

Try to use `$(".className").empty();`

```
Remove all child nodes of the set of matched elements from the DOM
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the following to clean the fields inside DIV

```
$('.addr').find('input:text').val('');
```